# How do I create auto-implemented properties in the VS class designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm using the class designer in Visual Studio 2008 and when I add properties to my classes they are created with an empty setter and a getter that throws a NotImplementedException. In the properties window there's an option called "Auto-Implemented" which is always greye out. Is there a way to change the settings for this so by default new properties will be auto-implemented or some way to turn this option on so I don't have to keep editing the code each time I add in a new property?

Comment: I have upgraded the ["Power Toys" add-in](http://modeling.codeplex.com/) that lets you do this to support Visual Studio 2013: http://saebamini.com/blog/post/2014/10/04/modeling-power-toys-for-visual-studio-2013

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't. I asked this at Barcelona a year or so ago - I don't think anything has changed. Basically, as I understand it, this is done directly (not via an editable snippet).

Comment: Still valid answer with VS 2010 Ultimate :S

Comment: Also still valid for VS2013 Ultimate :(

Comment: @Ytrog, there's an [add-in](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26195782/68080) that adds this functionality.

Answer (score 3):

For visual studio 2008
you could install this "power toys" that give you another option to class designer menu
"create auto-implemented property"

http://modeling.codeplex.com/

i'll waiting this for Visual Studio 2010 too... else it's so annoying

Answer (score 0):

You can create field, and encapsulate  it(Refactor->Encapsulate field).
This can help for simple properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a property by using snippet `propfull`, then Tab, Tab.