# Is it possible to configure the Class Diagram view to generate auto-implemented properties, rather than non-implemented ones?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, code-generation, class-diagram

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create auto-implemented properties in the VS class designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518252/how-do-i-create-auto-implemented-properties-in-the-vs-class-designer)

I often use the class diagram feature of Visual Studio to add properties to classes, but I'm often disappointed with the code it generates; Is it possible to configure the Class Diagram view to generate auto-implemented properties, rather than non-implemented ones?

i.e. instead of:

```
public PostCode PostCode
{
    get
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
    set
    {
    }
}
```

I'd prefer it to generate:

```
public PostCode PostCode { get; set; }
```